# rand number generator with limits in ruby

Tags: ruby, random

I have an array of 1000 numbers, randomly generated. 10 of those numbers must be between 0-9 (including 0 and 9), and 10 of those numbers must be between 991 and 1000 (including 991 and 1000). This is what I came up with:

```
arr = []
980.times do
  arr << (11..989).to_a.sample
end

arr2 = []
10.times do 
  arr2 << rand(10)
end

arr3 = []
10.times do
  arr3 << (990..1000).to_a.sample
end

arr4 = []
arr4 = arr + arr2 + arr3

arr4.shuffle
```

Is there a more elegant way to do this in ruby?

Comment: Is it only 10 for ranges at the end or "at least 10"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some notes:

- Try to learn some functional programming, you shouldn't write Ruby as it were a low-level language (like C). Favor expressions over statements. My 2-cents on the matter, I hope it helps: http://www.slideshare.net/tokland/functional-programming-with-ruby-9975242
- Let me show a simple example of using FP. The first 4 lines of your code could be written like this: `arr = 980.times.map { (11..989).to_a.sample }`
- `arr4 = []`: Why? the next line assigns it to another expression.
- `range.to_a.sample`. That's very inefficient, better `rand(range)`.

I'd write:

```
ranges = [0..9, 11..989, 990..1000]
output = ranges.flat_map do |range|
  range.map { rand(range) }
end.shuffle
```

Comment: I can't improve on your "I'd write:", but here's a variant: `ranges.reduce([]) {|arr, range| arr + Array.new(range.size) {rand(range)}}.shuffle`

Comment: @CarySwoveland: Not that efficiency is important here (those are small arrays), but note that `reduce` with `+` leads to O(n^2) code.

Answer (score 1):

Be careful at the boundaries — you didn't implement what you wanted.  The output will never contain 10, and it might include 990 among the [991, 1000] range.